# How does numpy frompyfunc generate ufunc form a python function containing if statements?

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote the following sample code, and I am a bit curious about how will `np.frompyfunc` work in this case.

```
import numpy as np
def test(x):
    if x>10000:
        return test(x)
    else:
        return x+1
def f(x, y):
    if y >5:
        x=test(x)
        return x/y
    if x<5:
        y+=1
        return x*y
    return x*y*2

vf = np.frompyfunc(f,2,1)
print(vf(np.arange(10),np.arange(10,0,-1)))
```

I guess it will somehow "flatten" the IF statement in the function and produce vectorized code, but I couldn't find the corresponding code in the numpy code repo.

Comment: source is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/f6c4dacc3b8f6dda3920a5ae6ebe48758a47e00d/numpy/core/src/umath/umathmodule.c)

Comment: In various time tests I've found that `frompyfunc` gives about a 2x speed improvement compared to an explicit (e.g. list comprension) implementation.  It's more of a broadcasting convenience, than a speed tool.

Comment: `np.vectorize` in the original form just uses `frompyfunc`, and tends to be a bit slower.  It just adds some control over the return `dtype`.  There's a new `signature` parameter, but it's an explicit loop, and slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`frompyfunc` cannot analyze your function or implicitly vectorize its execution. Its implementation is basically a `for` loop, calling your function repeatedly.

[Here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.3/numpy/core/src/umath/umathmodule.c#L85) is a link to the implementation of `frompyfunc` itself, although most of the parts you're interested in don't happen there. [Here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.3/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c.src#L608) is a link to one of the ufunc inner loops used for ufuncs created from Python objects; I believe `frompyfunc` will use that or one of the loops shortly above it in the source code. You can see the repeated use of `PyEval_CallObject` to call the Python callable.

Comment: Will [np.vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) also not vectorize the execution? It seems to call frompyfunc underhood.

Comment: @lin: If you want something that works at C speed, try Numba. I think they've got a numba.vectorize that actually does what you want. numpy.vectorize is also basically a `for` loop.